# Ruby enumerable block variable assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, destructuring, enumerable

Given this ERB code

```
<% @client.sessionables.ordered.by_program_completion.reverse_each do | program_name_and_completion, sessionables | %>
  <% program_name, program_completion_date = program_name_and_completion %>

  <% # Render stuff... %>
<% end %>
```

I would like to get rid of the second line, where I use the multiple variable assignment to extract `program_name` and `program_completion_date` from the `program_name_and_completion` array. One would assume it could be done directly in the block assignment, e.g.

```rb
sessionables.by_program_completion.each do | [program_name, program_completion_date], sessionables |
```

but the above snippet doesn't work, so my questions are:

1. Is this at all possible with Ruby?
2. If so, what's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the arguments inline as follows:

```
<% @client.sessionables.ordered.by_program_completion.reverse_each do |(program_name, program_completion_date), sessionables| %>
```

Or to write the same thing using less verbose syntax (so it's easier to see what's going on!!):

```
[[[1, 2], 3]].each { |(a, b), c| ... }
```

Inside the block, we get: `a == 1, b == 2, c == 3`.